# Linear Operator on Infinite Sums

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations

I'm currently self-studying partial differential equations using the book: An Introduction to Partial Differential Equations with MATLAB.

The textbook uses $L[u]=0$ (the linear operator) to define a linear, homogeneous PDE.

On the chapter on linear PDEs, it mentions that often, we need to find infinitely many solutions $\\u_1,u_2, ...$for a linear, homogeneous PDE before we can construct a general solution for the PDE:

$u=c_1u_1+c_2u_2+...=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_ku_k$

The book also assumes that linearity works on this infinite sum (Given that the infinite sum converges). That is,

$L[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_ku_k]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_kL[u_k]$

Why can we assume that we can 'expand' the linear operator into the infinite sum? I tried using the limit for the partial sums, however I was unable to continue as I have a lack of knowledge in this area.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Yes I'm asking the first thing that you mentioned. Can we actually expand the linear operator into the infinite sum? I thought we can only do that generally for finite sums? I've only proven it for finite sums; using mathematical induction. But I cannot rigorously justify it for infinite sums.

Comment: Ah okay. I wasn't thinking about the infinite part, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your comment though! I have edited the question to make it more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking you need more than linearity to establish that is preserves *infinite* sums.  You need some sort of continuity.  But it is likely true in situations dealt with in an elementary textbook.  In functional analysis one studies this more carefully.  Thing like the *closed graph theorem* show that continuity is easy to prove in reasonable settings.